# Creating buttons with a for loop? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, uibutton

```
 func makeAButton(){
        var tag = 1 

        for post in postArray {

            let cgX = CGFloat(post.x!)
            let cgY = CGFloat(post.y!)

let button : DragImg = DragImg(frame: CGRect(x: cgX, y: cgY, width: 100, height: 100))

            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            button.setTitle(post.user, forState: .Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            button.tag = tag
            self.view.addSubview(button)

            print(tag)

            tag += 1
        }

    }
```

I've currently got 7 things in my post array, and when I print out the tag, I get the

1
2
3
... and so on up to 7.

Whats happening though is that at the 0th item in the aray, 1 button is being created. Then at the 1st, 2 are being created at that x/y, and it keeps going up and up until I'm getting 7 buttons right ontop of eachother.

Why is this the case? I thought here the for loop would say:

For each post in PostArray make a single button using the data from that item in the PostArray.

How might I change this to work as intended?

Edit: (Just posting everything I've got)

```
import UIKit

import Firebase

class testController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    var colorsArray = [String]()
    var currentX = CGFloat()
    var currentY = CGFloat()
    var postArray = [CirclePost]()

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let position :CGPoint = touch.locationInView(view)

            currentY = position.y 
            currentX = position.x

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        DataService.ds.REF_BASE.child("Colors").observeEventType(.Value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

               self.postArray = []

            for snap in snapshots {


 if let x = snap.value!["x"] as? CGFloat,  y = snap.value!["y"] as? CGFloat, color = snap.value!["color"] as? String {
let post = CirclePost(postKey: snap.key, user: color , x: x, y: y)

                    self.postArray.append(post)
                    print(self.postArray.count)
                    self.makeAButton()

                }  
        }
            }


        }

    }

    func makeAButton(){

        var tag = 1

        for post in postArray {

        let cgX = CGFloat(post.x!)
        let cgY = CGFloat(post.y!)

        // let  button = DragImg()
        let button : DragImg = DragImg(frame: CGRect(x: cgX, y: cgY, width: 100, height: 100))

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        button.setTitle(post.user, forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button.tag = tag
        self.view.addSubview(button)


            tag += 1
        }

    }

    func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

        let button = postArray[sender.tag - 1] 
        print(button.user)
        print("Button tapped")
    }



    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

      let ref = DataService.ds.REF_BASE.child("Colors").childByAutoId()

       ref.child("color").setValue(textField.text)
       ref.child("x").setValue(currentX)
       ref.child("y").setValue(currentY)



    }


}
```

Comment: What type is a post? What is post.x? Are all of the buttons stacked on top of each other?

Comment: @WMios

post is just a class that's pulling information back from Firebase. 

post.x  and y are x/y values that are set by users when they touch the screen and make the button. 

I'm also now running into an issue where when I make a new "post", every single button is recreated again despite me clearing out the array when that happens? 

I'm gonna just add the entirety of my code as an edit, it's not all that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your issue:

```
for snap in snapshots {
...
    self.postArray.append(post)
    print(self.postArray.count)
    self.makeAButton()
```

You're adding a post to the array, then drawing the array (1 item). Then next time you add an additional post and then draw the array (2 items) and so on.

You need to move the call `self.makeAButton()` out of that for loop.

Comment: That definitely fixed that issue. Only one is being made at each location now on load. Awesome!

Any ideas how to fix the second bit though? When I'm manually doing the "buttonPressed" to post up new data to firebase about a new button to be made, I'm getting every single button recreated. 

I guess it doesn't work exactly like tableView.reload data me clearing out the array in my observer. Does just removing the subviews and allowing everything to be completely redrawn make sense here? Like I guess adding the subviews into some array, and then when a new Value comes in, remove those views

Comment: Yeah just delete the subviews before drawing again

Comment: And that's the best way to go about it? Just like when I make a button, add it into some array, and then delete that array out in my Observer when it's called yeah?

Thanks for the help man, apprecaite it a lot!

Comment: Glad to have helped. If what I said about that last bit doesn't work just ask another question.

Comment: Works like a charm.